# Error when using sendEmail

Tags: smtp, gmail

I'm trying to learn how to use `sendEmail` to send automated emails. This is the command I entered in Windows command prompt:

```
sendEmail -f myemail@gmail.com -t youremail@gmail.com -m This is a test message. -s smtp.gmail.com:465 -xu myemail@gmail.com -xp mypassword
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR => Connection attempt to smtp.gmail.com:465 failed: IO::SOCKET::INET: Bad hostname 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

After researching this problem online, I ran telnet on `smtp.gmail.com`, and found that I could not open a connection. I think this is the problem, though I am still unsure what is causing it. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It might be that TLS is required. Try adding `-o tls=auto` and see how it goes.

Comment: I also had the same issue. I used the -o tls=true. But no use. And I followed the Sayid Locke advice and placed the "74.125.203.109 smtp.gmail.com" in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host file. But now there other error is coming. That is : "smtp.gmail.com:587 failed: IO::Socket::INET: connect: Unknown error"

Answer (score 2):

Update /etc/hosts, add a ip address to smtp.gmail.com:

```
74.125.203.109 smtp.gmail.com
```

Update /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Worked for me using /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

IO::SOCKET::INET: IPV6 - Error may also cause such this kind of issues. [check it by typing ifconfig/ipconfig].
If there are multiple IPV6 addresses, then disconnect your network and reconnect it. [eth0 ifdown & eth0 ifup]

[image]